# What's going on in the opening comic?

Tags: cloud-breakers

Cloubreakers is awesome, but I'm still not exactly sure what the premise (such as it is) is all about.  The little comic that shows every time you launch the game is a bit vague.

I can see Japan Friend in that third panel breaking apart, which explains why you need to collect three pieces of each character to unlock them, but everything else about this image is kind of confusing.  Is Strong Bro attacking them in the first panel?

[image: Cloudbreakers opening comic]

Comment: Where exactly can you find this game? Searching 'cloud breakers' on Google doesn't give me anything about this game in particular, rather a mobile game called Cloud Breaker.

Comment: Sorry, it's *[Cloudbreakers](http://touchtronicarcade.cz/)*, not *Cloud Breakers*.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the image provided, it looks like all the characters are attempting to help the one hanging off the side of the cliff and pull him back up, while the cliff gives in and breaks. As a result, everyone ends up falling and breaking apart.

I have not played this game before, so all of this is just an educated guess based on what I can see in the image.